# Performance spikes observed in unity profiler after adding the google-VR module

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, google-vr, gfx

while a simple mobile unity game project (or a simple project with a cube and a camera) provides almost uniform CPU time with less variation while profiling it.

But adding the googleVR (tried latest and old versions) module to it, split into left and right eye (GVRviewer) and profile the VR mobile app provides a lot of spikes or variations which is due to VR.waitforGPU() and in turn gfx.processcommands(). can anyone please tell me **what's the reason behind those performance spikes while adding GVR module** ?

I have tried multiple optimizations (e.g. static batching, disabling vsync, optimizing mesh data) but nothing seems to be useful. Is there any possible way to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Is it a real "issue"? I mean do you actually notice a difference on the device? Sometimes it is simply not possible to avoid "spikes" but if it is a "spike" e.g. increasing render time from 0,2ms to 1,0ms I'ld say it's still nothing to worry about ..

Comment: Yes, I found it after adding the GVR module and this performance spike is quite frequent. I use a simple project with fixed camera and looking at a cube. In this case, I think the render timing should n't vary that much which I got for normal mobile games but not for VR. I need to resolve the issue as this sudden spike sometime can result frame loss for some other VR games which may affect adjacent frames. Any clue regarding this?